# Failed to retrieve information about the Bazel workspace

Tags: mediapipe

When running MediaPipe.tulsiproj on Tulsi, the following error occurred. Please tell me the solution

```
ERROR: /Users/a/mediapipe/mediapipe/examples/ios/helloworld/BUILD:34:16: no such target '//mediapipe/examples/ios:developer_provisioning_profile': target 'developer_provisioning_profile' not declared in package 'mediapipe/examples/ios' defined by /Users/a/mediapipe/mediapipe/examples/ios/BUILD (Tip: use `query "//mediapipe/examples/ios:*"` to see all the targets in that package) and referenced by '//mediapipe/examples/ios/helloworld:HelloWorldApp'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/ios/helloworld:HelloWorldApp' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
General failure: Bazel aspects could not be built.
```

I executed Hello world and it worked fine.